# Clojure compile error - Unable to resolve symbol: this in this context

Tags: clojure

Just when I thought I had seen it all in Clojure errors I get one that is baffling. When compiling my .clj file using `lein compile` I'm getting this exception:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resolve symbol: this in this context, compiling:(medical_notes/read_notes.clj:135:26)
```

the line in the read_notes.clj file that it is pointing to (135) is simply

```
{:type :compute}
```

that's it. The word "this" does not appear anywhere in the file. That line is inside this function:

```
(defn m-compute
 "Message sent to master to start the computation"
 []
 {:type :compute})
```

Anyone have any idea what is confusing it?

UPDATE: after troubleshooting and trying different things I can at least say now that the line number reported with the error is totally wrong for sure. It always reports exactly the same line number (135:26) no matter what. Right now line 135 in the file is a blank line and it's still calling out that line as the problem.

Comment: How are you calling m-compute?

Comment: It's being called like this: `(.tell coordinator (m-compute) nil)`

Comment: try inlining `{:type :compute}` into your function call to help diagnose if the issue is in the function declaration itself.

Comment: As an aside, a function call isn't the best way to represent static data like this.  I'd recommend `(def m-compute {:type :compute})` called like this: `(.tell coordinator m-compute nil)`.

Comment: I inlined that map and commented out the function declaration. I get exactly the same error when compiling. It even still points to line 135 which is now a commented line. Something here is really confusing the compiler.

Comment: Did you check that this is actually the good file ? Like by putting some garbage on top ?

Comment: Yes, putting `gsgsgs` inside the file gives me `Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resolve symbol: gsgsgs in this context` when I try to compile. However, it doesn't point to the right line in the file. The error seems to point to line 1, but the garbage symbol is at line 21